# Android 14 predictive back gesture - blinking white background color

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-14, predictive-back

[According to the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/custom-back/predictive-back-gesture), we simply should update `'androidx.activity:activity'` version in the `build.gradle` and add `android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"` to the Manifest to make predictive back work. I made both changes, the animation works in general, but the screen is blinking white while transitioning from my Activity Two to Activity One. I believe it's something like a global background of the app, however, `android:windowBackground` is dark in both activities. Both activities are `ComponentActivity` and the UI is Jetpack Compose based (there are no Composables with white background). What have I missed?

[image]

**Update:** I created a new project with two activities:

```
class Activity1 : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(Color.Black)) {
                Button(onClick = {
                    startActivity(Intent(this@Activity1, Activity2::class.java))
                }) {
                    Text(text = "TO ACTIVITY 2", color = Color.White)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class Activity2: ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(Color.Black)) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

the theme for both activities is:

```
<style name="Theme.PredBackTest" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

however, the result is same - it's blinking white while moving back from Activity2 to Activity1.

Comment: Is device theme light?

Comment: @plplmax no, it's dark

Comment: try base theme android:Theme.Material.DayNight

Comment: @ArdaKazancı ah you are totally right. I missed that it sets Light theme as default. DayNight theme fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your theme `android:Theme.Material.DayNight`

Comment: Just a quick note for others looking for the answer - if you don't have ```android:Theme.Material.DayNight```, add ```com.google.android.material:material:x.x.x``` to the dependencies and use ```Theme.Material3.DayNight```

Comment: This only turns white blink into black blink. It still blinks annoyingly.

Answer (score 0):

What we did to workaround for this is disable predictive back on every activity except our main activity (only one that actually exits out of the app): https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/custom-back/predictive-back-gesture#opt-activity-level

```
<manifest ...>
<application . . .

    android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="false">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"
        ...
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="false"
        ...
    </activity>
</application>
```

Ideal fix for this would be transitioning to single activity, but until this is done, above workaround would do.

Not sure why Google decided on this blinking animation for Android 14, it looks terrible for on our apps.