# Android 14 predictive back background color mismatch

Tags: android, material-components-android, predictive-back

I am implementing predictive back in my android app and am facing a problem. In the left screenshot below, the redder color is my `android:windowBackground` and I am in the process of doing a predictive back. As you can see, around the red area in a darker color. What I want is for the the predictive back background color to blend in with the app background color as is done in e.g. the settings app, see the right image.

[image: Current behavior]
[image: Desired behavior]

The theme I use inherits from `Theme.Material3.Dark.NoActionBar`, both activities inherit from `AppCompatActivity` and I use `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0-alpha03'`.

Meanwhile if I set the app to use a light theme, I get a white backdrop during predictive back which again does not agree with the set `android:windowBackground`.

In case anyone wants to have a deeper look at the specific code used in this example the app is open source at [GitHub](https://github.com/SimonHalvdansson/Harmonic-HN) but I really do believe this to be a question of general interest and the [previous Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77253913/android-14-predictive-back-gesture-blinking-white-background-color) is similar but does not seem to be the same (I get correct dark/light predictive backdrop but I want to fully match the window background as in the settings app).

Comment: Have you tried using the android:Theme.Material.DayNight theme?

Comment: @ArdaKazancı that precise theme does not resolve for me, specifically in this context: `<style name="AppThemeMaterialDayNight" parent="android:Theme.Material.DayNight"></style>`.

Comment: This is for your problem. You need to use Dynamic Colors.

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/theming/dynamic-colors?hl=en

Comment: @ΓDΛ I set all fo those colors to red (just so it'd be noticable) and the backdrop still did not change color.

Comment: You can also use the android:windowBackgroundOverlay attribute to set a translucent overlay over the app background color. This can be used to create a more subtle effect than simply setting the android:windowBackground attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of looking, I found out that this property is set by `<item name="android:colorBackground">@color/my_background_color</item>` in the app theme. Specifically, to get the same effect as in the settings app, one should set this values to the same as `android:windowBackground`.

Answer (score 1):

> I get correct dark/light predictive backdrop but I want to fully match the window background as in the settings app).

The predictive back light/dark colors are system wide colors that are determined when the user changes the theme of their device.

The predictive back color looks like the same in both shared screenshots of the Settings app and your own app, that's because it's a sole color for the current theme/darkness mode picked by the user.

However, in the Settings app, the predictive back color looks coherent with the app's background color because the Settings app is a System app that is entirely styled with the system-wide colors (which are coherent by default).

The user can pick their preferred theme from the device settings, On Google Pixel 7 Pro: **Settings > Wallpaper & style > System colors**

[image]

So, as of writing this answer, unfortunately the predictive back color is not a something that can be controlled by developers, but users.

Comment: In my app, my Material You llight background color is precisely the same one as in the settings app however the backdrop is white (which is not the case for the settings app). The Material You selection of colors is what I am using to select the background color in the app. So I am using system colors, just like the Settings app, yet I don't get the same backdrop as the settings app.

Comment: @SweSnow I just tried your repo, I couldn't get that white color, or maybe I am missing something, can you elaborate more how to regenerate that on your own project